# Role capability issue

Tags: admin-menu, capabilities, user-roles, add-submenu-page

I have a custom sub menu item that has been setup for a long time and all of a sudden today one Role cannot see the item on the Tools menu. They can see a couple of other items on that same Tools menu that the Role has the capability, but not this one....

```
add_submenu_page( 'tools.php', 'Reports', 'Reports', 'read', 'ourreports', 'our_tools_page');
```

I reduced the capability to 'read' from a custom capability just to test and still they cannot see. We use Adminimizer, Advanced Menu Editor and User Role Editor plugins. I've checked all those and verified the Role has read permissions and is not deactivated in Adminimizer. If I copy the link in question (/wp-admin/tools.php?page=ourreports) while logged in as any other user that has the capability to view the Tools menu, and then paste into the browser while logged in a user of this problem Role, it shows I do not have access...

```
Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.
```

Where else can I look to solve this issue with the Role not being able to View my custom sub menu page?

We also have a development copy of this website where the problem does not exist, the Role can view the custom sub menu item without issue. I have verified WordPress core and all plugins match and up-to-date. So, I feel there is a setting by someone somewhere I'm not thinking to look.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Having a similar problem.